# Cannot put a file in an existing directory structure using Jenkins automation

Tags: jenkins, automation, jmeter, dockerfile, tar

I'm having an issue writing a file to a directory created from a prior curl/tar command. I can create a subdirectory under the existing directory structure, but I cannot place a file using a tar command in that preexisting directory structure.

In other words, I want to put a .jar file in the /opt/$JMETER_VERSION/lib directory, and cannot. The weird part is that I can create a subdirectory under /opt/$JMETER_VERSION/lib and can put a file in that, but I cannot use a tar command, nor a mv or cp to put a file in the /lib directory.

I did a "chmod +w /opt/$JMETER_VERSION/lib" and also did a "ls -l -R /opt" and everything shows up as being under root, which is what I'm under while doing this automation from within a dockerfile. Any idea why I can't write to /opt/$JMETER_VERSION/lib?

The tar command below is causing the automation to fail -

&& curl -fsSL --compressed -o /tmp/mysql-connector.tar.gz https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/get/p/3/file/mysql-connector-java-6.0.3.tar.gz 
&& chmod +w /opt/$JMETER_VERSION/lib
&& tar -C /opt/$JMETER_VERSION/lib -xzvf /tmp/mysql-connector.tar.gz --strip-components 1 mysql-connector-java-6.0.3/mysql-connector-java-6.0.3-bin.jar \

Answer (score 0):

Given your user is able to create this `/opt/$JMETER_VERSION` directory it should have write access there already.

I don't think it's possible to extract a single file from a tarball without keeping the whole directory structure so I would recommend extracting `mysql-connector-java-6.0.3` folder, moving `mysql-connector-java-6.0.3-bin.jar` from it to JMeter's "lib" folder (or other folder which is in [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)) and performing cleanup of the /tmp folder.

Example [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/)

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-slim

ARG JMETER_VERSION=apache-jmeter-5.4.1
ARG JMETER_DOWNLOAD_URL=https://archive.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/${JMETER_VERSION}.tgz

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
    curl procps && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* 

RUN mkdir -p /opt/${JMETER_VERSION} \
  && curl -fsSL -o /tmp/apache-jmeter.tar.gz ${JMETER_DOWNLOAD_URL} \
  && tar -xzf /tmp/apache-jmeter.tar.gz -C /opt/${JMETER_VERSION} --strip-components=1 \
  && rm -f /tmp/apache-jmeter.tar.gz \
  && curl -fsSL --compressed -o /tmp/mysql-connector.tar.gz https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/get/p/3/file/mysql-connector-java-6.0.3.tar.gz \
  && tar -xzf /tmp/mysql-connector.tar.gz -C /tmp mysql-connector-java-6.0.3/mysql-connector-java-6.0.3-bin.jar \
  && mv /tmp/mysql-connector-java-6.0.3/mysql-connector-java-6.0.3-bin.jar /opt/${JMETER_VERSION}/lib \
  && rm -rf /tmp/mysql-connector*
```

More information: [Make Use of Docker with JMeter - Learn How](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/make-use-of-docker-with-jmeter-learn-how)

Comment: I have tried doing the move as well from a different directory that I wrote the jar file to, and that also makes the automation fail. I have tested extracting just a single file. The single file extraction works. Just not to the already created /lib folder.

Comment: FWIW - The automation is executing on a a docker container on an AWS EC2 that is locked down, so I don't really have access to it. When the automation fails, I don't get the user-data.log file so can't see what the error is, only that the job failed.

Answer (score 0):

If it helps, here is the RUN command with the issue. If I comment out the tar command above the commented line in the middle, the automation passes, but I of course don't get the .jar file I need.

**Install JMeter, MySQL Connector for JMeter, plugins manager and plugins (non-deprecated)**

```
RUN curl -fsSL --compressed -o /tmp/jmeter.tgz https://archive.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/$JMETER_VERSION.tgz \
    && tar -C /opt -xzvf /tmp/jmeter.tgz \
    && rm /tmp/jmeter.tgz \
    && curl -fsSL --compressed -o /tmp/mysql-connector.tar.gz https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/get/p/3/file/mysql-connector-java-6.0.3.tar.gz \
    && chmod +w /opt/$JMETER_VERSION/lib
    && tar -C /opt/$JMETER_VERSION/lib -xzvf /tmp/mysql-connector.tar.gz --strip-components 1 mysql-connector-java-6.0.3/mysql-connector-java-6.0.3-bin.jar \
    # && tar -C /tmp -xzvf /tmp/mysql-connector.tar.gz --strip-components 1 mysql-connector-java-6.0.3/mysql-connector-java-6.0.3-bin.jar \
    && rm /tmp/mysql-connector.tar.gz \
    && curl -fsSL --compressed -o /opt/$JMETER_VERSION/lib/ext/jmeter-plugins-manager.jar https://jmeter-plugins.org/get \
    && curl -fsSL --compressed -o /opt/$JMETER_VERSION/lib/cmdrunner-$CMDRUNNER_VERSION.jar https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/kg/apc/cmdrunner/$CMDRUNNER_VERSION/cmdrunner-$CMDRUNNER_VERSION.jar\
    && java -cp /opt/$JMETER_VERSION/lib/ext/jmeter-plugins-manager.jar org.jmeterplugins.repository.PluginManagerCMDInstaller \
    && /opt/$JMETER_VERSION/bin/PluginsManagerCMD.sh install-all-except jpgc-hadoop,jpgc-oauth,ulp-jmeter-gwt-plugin,ulp-jmeter-autocorrelator-plugin,ulp-jmeter-videostreaming-plugin \
    && sleep 2 \
    && /opt/$JMETER_VERSION/bin/PluginsManagerCMD.sh status
```